# Eclipse android application runs on android device but not on emulator [error message]

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm developing an Android application on Eclipse. When I run it with an Android device hooked up (e.g. a Samsung phone) it runs just fine.

However when I run it with the Android emulator I run into a problem. The application opens correctly to the log-in page. After I input my login/password, the application crashes as it is "Logging In...".

I get the following message:

"Unfortunately, [AppName] has stopped working."

I was hoping someone here could help me out or point me in the right direction. It looks like the emulator crashes when it tries to contact the server where the login information is held. Every time the LogCat shows an error that says "can't reach *_*_.edu"

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: A possibility is that you are trying to connect to the server in the main thread..post the logcat..

Comment: ... or that your emulator does not have network access

Comment: thanks for the response. how do i post the logcat? do i do it from eclipse or from terminal (btw i'm on windows)

Comment: Just copy and paste from Eclipse.  Edit your question, not in a comment please.